# Third Party Flash for Portraits

Tags: canon, flash, portrait

Can you tell me what sort of flash is being used in the following picture and where can I get one of those?

http://photos-e.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xfa1/914797_708687699196740_706239400_n.jpg

(Note that the linked image is NSFW)

Comment: It's not a flash, it's an LED panel. See: http://www.kirktuck.com/site/Books.html

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a flash unit, these on-camera LED panels will typically stay lit, allowing you to compose your shot and adjust your camera's settings accordingly. You can buy LED lighting units such as these at many online retailers, such as [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2/181-2056440-1186622?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=led%20flash&sprefix=led%20flash%2Caps%2C290) or [B&H Photo](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/On-Camera-Lights/ci/2026/N/4011740573). There are many highly rated yet cost effective offerings at either of those links. Make sure to read the product reviews to gauge what is going to best fit your shooting style.